# "Enter" pressed in text within a textbox does not appear on PDF export

Tags: php, laravel, enter

When a "enter" is pressed inside a textbox it does not appear on a PDF export page. The text appears like one long sentence.

Its in Laravel, i use dompdf for the PDF export.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

use function `nl2br` to your output from textarea